# Stopping baker and getting balance unfrozen

Tags: baking, baking-rights

Let's say I stop baking 1/4th of the way through cycle 500 by stopping all baking processes. When should I expect to get 100% of my balance back?

I did not set frozen deposit limit to 0 before stopping the processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Jakarta protocol documentation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/active/proof_of_stake.html):

> A delegate becomes passive at the end of cycle n when it has failed to participate in the consensus algorithm in the past PRESERVED_CYCLES + 1 cycles, that is, in cycles n, n-1, n-2, …, n - PRESERVED_CYCLES.

And

> At the end of cycle n-1-PRESERVED_CYCLES, the snapshot for cycle n is randomly selected from the snapshots stored in cycle n-1-PRESERVED_CYCLES.

`PRESERVED_CYCLES` is 5 on mainnet.

So if you go offline sometimes during cycle 500, you will be marked as passive at cycle 507, and you won't be assigned rights for cycle 513.

You will have a bonded balance until the end of cycle 512.

To get your deposit back faster, set your deposit limit to zero or transfer the free balance out of your baking address.